# Use BerkeleyParser.jar in django (views.py), but get a empty output file

Tags: java, python, django

I use the following code in a views.py

```
def berkeleyParser(infile,outfile):   
    cmd="java -Xmx1024m -jar nlptools/BerkeleyParser/berkeleyParser-1.7.jar -gr nlptools/BerkeleyParser/chn_sm5.gr < "+infile+" > "+outfile 
    os.system(cmd)
```

and then call this function to use berkeley parser.
I think the file path is ok, because the jar can successfully create the output file.

Meanwhile, I use a independent .py code to run the code above (with path modified), and got correct result in output file.

So, I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Is the class path correct from django's perspective? The relative path to the jar file strikes me as the first possible problem. Is the `java` binary in the path the django server runs with? Where do you call `berkeleyParser()` from?

Comment: I call this function in the same code file. I think the class path is correct, because django told me it can't access the jar file, and then I changed the path and this error disappeared. The jar file can even successfully generate the output file, but with no content.

Comment: And `infile` and `outfile` are both in the correct location and their paths do not contain spaces?

Comment: yes, I run this cmd in anothor python file independently and can get correct result, using the same inputfile and both infile and outfile paths. So the encoding of inputfile is also correct.